# Display ItemCode and Price

Tags: php, arrays

I have a table of Items and a table of prices.

For each item I want to display several prices based on the quantity purchased.
How is it possible to do this.

I wonder if the proper way to do this like so:

```
foreach ($items as $key => $item):

echo $item['itemcode'];

    foreach($prices as $key => $price):
        echo $price['price'];
    endforeach;

endforeach;
```

if so, how can I bind the itemCode in my $prices array?

Comment: You might want to be more explicit about the arrays/data you refer to and the way you would like to combine them exactly - a sample with expected outcome would be helpful.

Comment: I have two arrays I get from a database, one being the $items and the other the $prices. In the $items I have 'itemcode' (Pk) , 'itemname'. In the $prices array 'itemcode' (Fk) and 'price', 'qty'. I want to display a boostrap card with the item and the prices for the item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using an if statement in the nested foreach.

Below is the php code

```
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-12">
                    <img class="img-fluid rounded float-left" src="img/items/99810002.CN1_01.JPG" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <h2><?php echo $articolo['ItemCode']; ?></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <ul>
                    <?php
                    foreach ($prezzi as $key => $prezzo):?>
                    <?php
                        if($prezzo['ItemCode'] == $articolo['ItemCode']){
                            echo "<h1 class='card-title pricing-card-title'>" . $prezzo['ItemPrice'] . "<small class='text-muted'>/ mo</small></h1>";
                        }
                    ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```